# .CSV Data Loading (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How to load data into my table?

Maria DB was installed:'Not supported' but it must work.
[image]

Comment: It looks like it might be having trouble loading the file at the given path, is the path correct?

Comment: That's the point I wanna know...
I use Linux version of MySQL Workbench.